# Partial search is not working with match_phrase_prefix in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

### We are using Elasticsearch 7.10.2 & trying to search records with query type match_phrase_prefix but not getting expected results for partial search, only getting 1 hits with score 494.16815

## **

##### mapping for name field is

```
"name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "custom-index-analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "custom-search-analyzer"
                }
```

##### settings of analyzer

```
"analyzer": {
                        custom-search-analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "custom-ascii-folding",
                                "custom-stopword",
                                "lowercase",
                                "custom-synonym"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                                "custom-html-strip"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        },
                        custom-index-analyzer": {
                            "filter": [
                                "custom-ascii-folding",
                                "lowercase"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                                "custom-html-strip"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                        }
                    }
```

> filters

```
"filter": {
                        "custom-ascii-folding": {
                            "type": "asciifolding",
                            "preserve_original": "true"
                        },
                        "custom-stopword": {
                            "ignore_case": "true",
                            "type": "stop",
                            "stopwords_path": "analyzers/FT9797"
                        },
                        "custom-synonym": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms_path": "analyzers/R30234",
                            "updateable": "true"
                        }
                    }

synonyms:

    est, east
    ouest, west
    nord, north
    vieux, old



stopwords:
         and
         at
         inclusive
         a
```

> expected result should be records which have first word as las and second should be start with v.
> We have more than 100 records for this scenario like "las vegas", "las vecas" & etc.

query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": {
                "query": "las v"
            }
        }
    }
}

expected results :

[
  "las vegas",
  "las villas,
  "las vacas"
]
```

query output: 1 hits only

> We have more than 50 records for search term las vegas, below query is providing the results with 77 hits

query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": {
                "query": "las vegas"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### Event if we tried with las veg than getting results, some time it is working for last word with length 3 some time with length 4 and if we will increase max_expansions more than 200 then getting more than 10 records but not getting expected results.

##### We also tried with default setting & mappings (without synonyms & stopword) but that is also not working

Comment: Can you share your custom char filter and token filters so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: updated details with filter

Comment: thanks, but stop words and synonyms files are still missing

Comment: updated stopword and synonyms details

Comment: Ok, now provide a sample document (just the `name` field) that doesn't show up with your first query even though it should

Comment: updated expected results details as array of name

Comment: Yes, but how do the raw values look like? I indexed `las vegas` and the query works for that input

Comment: consider this example : {"hites":[{"_score":31.13784,"_source":{"name":"Las Vegas"}},{"_score":27.687166,"_source":{"name":"test Las Vegas"}},{"_score":24.924997,"_source":{"name":"test Las Vegas - waooo"}},{"_score":24.924997,"_source":{"name":"The test Las Vegas"}}]}

Comment: it is returning the data, event if I am trying with las veg, for las v only getting one record, if I am increasing max_expansions more than 200 then getting more than 10 records but not getting expected results even I tried with default setting & mappings #elasticsearch #val

Comment: update some points at the end